# Ionic relaxation with ASE (Atomic Simulation Environment)

Tags: python, atomic-simulation-environment

I want to do an ionic relaxation of just the ions inside my unit cell (not the cell dimensions), with Quantum Espresso through ASE. However, I have only been able to find structure optimization methods in the [documentation][1] that:

- Use ASE's own algorithms (not the QE methods one).
- Do not allow me to control what to relax and what to freeze (ie, cell dimensions, ions, etc)

So far this is what I have been able to produce.

```
from ase.calculators.espresso import Espresso
from ase.constraints import UnitCellFilter
from ase.optimize import LBFGS
from ase import Atoms

pseudopotentials = {'Cl': 'Cl.pz-nl-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF',
                            'Na': 'Na.pz-spnl-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF'}

symbols = ["Na", "Na", "Na", "Na",
           "Cl", "Cl", "Cl", "Cl",]
cell = [[5.69, 0.00, 0.00],
        [0.00, 5.69, 0.00],
        [0.00, 0.00, 5.69]]
scaled_positions = [[0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
                    [0.00, 0.50, 0.50],
                    [0.50, 0.00, 0.50],
                    [0.50, 0.50, 0.00],
                    [0.50, 0.50, 0.50],
                    [0.50, 0.00, 0.00],
                    [0.00, 0.50, 0.00],
                    [0.00, 0.00, 0.50]]

rocksalt = Atoms(symbols=symbols,
                 scaled_positions=scaled_positions,
                 cell=cell,
                 pbc=True)

calc = Espresso(pseudopotentials=pseudopotentials,
                tstress=True,
                tprnfor=True,
                kpts=(1, 1, 1))
rocksalt.calc = calc

ucf = UnitCellFilter(rocksalt)
opt = LBFGS(ucf)
opt.run(fmax=0.005)
```

I was wondering if there is something along the lines of:

```
rocksalt.relaxation(cell=(x=False, y=False, z=False), ions=True)
```

[1][[https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/optimize.html]

Comment: I think you can do that using the UnitCellFilter object. Look at the arguments for UnitCellFilter [here](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/constraints.html), using the mask argument should be able to fix the cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use an ASE optimizer to relax your structure, it doesn't relax your unit cell by default. It is only necessary to use [`UnitCellFilter`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/constraints.html#ase.constraints.UnitCellFilter) when you **want to** simultaneously optimize the ionic positions and unit cell. In that case, I often use the improved version [`ExpCellFilter`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/constraints.html#the-expcellfilter-class).

Answer (score 2):

i) If you do *not* want to relax your unit cell dimension, do *not* use the `UnitCellFilter` or equivalent.

ii) I think you are looking for [the `constraints` module](https://gitlab.com/ase/ase/-/blob/master/ase/constraints.py) to fix positions. See also [the docs.](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/constraints.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).